# Give full permission for MS Access database in Microsoft Office Access Workgroup Information (.mdw) file

Tags: ms-access-2007

I am new to ms access, I have a Microsoft Office Access Workgroup Information (.mdw) file in my server, and I cannot change the details of some forms in database because of permission issue, How can I delete all permission? when I try to change the permission then one error message showing 'you cannot change the permission, to change permission for this object you must have administrator permission. I need to give full permission.

Thanks.